# Counterexample, Matsumura Exercise 2.5

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I try to find a counterexample of the exercise 2.5 in *Commutative Ring Theory* by Matsumura, when $A$ is not commutative. The exercise says.

> Let $A$ be a commutative ring. If $A^n \simeq A^m$, then $m = n$.

I have thought that the module $A^m$ has a minimal base with $n$ elements $\{x_1, ..., x_n\}$ and need to take the $\phi : A^n \rightarrow A^m$ such that $\phi (e_j) = x_j$ where $e_j$ is the canonical base.

Comment: The classical non-commutative example is the endomorphism ring of an infinite-dimensional vector space.

Comment: The keyword you are looking for is [invariant basis number](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_basis_number).